# Saving a Firestore object throws InvocationTargetException error

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

It's taken me around an hour to debug this issue so I was wondering whether someone would be able to explain what's going on here.

I'm trying to save a Firestore custom object on Android (in Kotlin). Here's a simplified version -

```
class MockTransaction {

    val endpoint: String = "mockTransactions"

    var fromAddress: String = ""
    var toAddress: String = ""
    var amount: Double = 0.0

    constructor() {}

    constructor(from: String, to: String, amount: Double) {
        this.fromAddress = from
        this.toAddress = to
        this.amount = amount
    }

    fun isValid(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    fun save() {
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection(endpoint).add(this).addOnCompleteListener {
            Log.d("TX", it.isSuccessful.toString() )
            Log.d("TX", it.exception.toString())
        }
    }

}

val tx = MockTransaction("Alice", "Bob", 100.0)
tx.save()
```

Now if I change the `isValid` function to throw an exception like so

```
fun isValid(): Boolean {
    throw TransactionException("No signature found")
}
```

The save method with throw an error

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

If I change the function *name* to simply `fun valid()` then the save works.

I'm just curious as to why the name of the function matters? I've also tried changing it to something like `fun isARadioactiveSpider()` and you get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A firebase class `CustomClassMapper` has a method:

```
private static boolean shouldIncludeGetter(Method method) {
    if (!method.getName().startsWith("get") && !method.getName().startsWith("is")) {
        return false;
    } else if (method.getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class)) {
        return false;
    } else if (!Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
        return false;
    } else if (Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) {
        return false;
    } else if (method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)) {
        return false;
    } else if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return !method.isAnnotationPresent(Exclude.class);
    }
}
```

So reflection is used to serialize methods that look like getters. Later these methods will be invoked using reflection. And this invocation throws some exception, which is hidden in `InvocationTargetException`

So, to avoid the `InvocationTargetException`, just check that methods don't throw exceptions, because they are invoked during the serialization